# cannot enable BigQuery for apps script project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Since yesterday I can no longer successfully enable the BigQuery API in my apps script projects. I have done this literally hundreds of times over the past months, so I am very familiar with the process. Since yesterday the enabling doesn't actually take effect anymore.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create or locate a BigQuery project & dataset, find the project numeric ID.
- In Google Drive create an apps script project
- Paste the following function:

```
    var projectNumber = '1111111111'; // Google cloud BigQuery project *number* not alphanumeric id

    function bqtest() {
      datasets = BigQuery.Datasets.list(projectNumber);
      Logger.log(datasets);
    }
```

- In [script > resources > advanced google resources] enable the BigQuery v2 API
- Try to run the function, you will get an OAuth authorization pop-up and will need to grant your script access to BigQuery
- You will then get an error that says that the BigQuery API needs to be enabled in the cloud console: `Access Not Configured. BigQuery API has not been used in project 111111111111 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/overview?project=111111111111 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. (line 5, file "Code")`
- Enable the BigQuery API in the google cloud console as instructed (tip: when you follow the URL click on "dashboard" in the left column, then "enable APIs" at the top) and verify that it's enabled
- Go back to the apps script and re-run the function, you will get the same error that the BQ API needs to be enabled.
- Since the error says that it may take a few minutes to propagate, go have some food, come back, try again, see the same error. I have waited overnight with no change. Normally it takes less than 10 seconds.

I have tried the above using my corporate G-suite account as well as my personal account and run into the same problem both ways.

Are others seeing the same? Where does one go for help?

Comment: Try to open an issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

This issue now appears resolved. I ended up having to sign up for silver support, pay $150, create a cloud support ticket, and eventually I got the reply "I've looked at this issue with our backend team. This is an incident that was reported today, and you're not the only one affected by it. It's a known issue. I will get back to you in a few hours with more updates." Oh great, I'm glad I got to pay to get that info :-(. So far the lack of support with GCP is confirming that I should continue spending my money elsewhere...